# Spring Boot datasorce (in application properties config) and JBoss 7 deployment transactions dont works

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, jboss7.x, spring-transactions

I have developed some APIs with Spring Boot 5 and I need to deploy it on a JBoss 7 EAP server.
The problem is that when deploying to the embedded server in Spring Boot, transaction management is correct (I am using Spring Data JPA for database management) when I set the @Transactional annotation, but if I deploy the wars in JBoss, transaction management does not work.

I have tried changing the datasource management to JNDI and this way works for me, but I want to keep the datasource management in the application.properties into Spring Boot.

Any idea how I should indicate either in JBoss or in the configuration of my APIs in Spring Boot to have correct transaction management?

Thanks!

I have searched but have not found information on how to configure Spring Boot with JBoss to perform transaction management